# Reversing MODULO operation ? system of equations

Tags: modular-arithmetic, systems-of-equations

i have 1000 prime numbers p1 ... p1000 .. which i use to encode a value

```
 v % p1 = r1
 v % p2 = r2
 v % p3 = r3
 ....
 v % p1000 = r1000
```

then I pick the 20 PRIMES which gives the SMALLEST reminders and store them.

Later I want to be able to recover back the VALUE (or approximate value) by only having the 20 PRIMES available, and knowing they give the smallest reminders out of the 1000.

btw i still have access to the 1000 primes

if it also helps I pick the sequence of 1000 primes above number N ... and for ease of use  I encode a NEW_VALUE = VALUE + BIGGEST_PRIME

---

```
  def encode(self, value) :
    mods = (value + self.max_prime) % self.primes
    return np.argsort(mods)[:20]
```

---

@lulu

finding multiple values that match the prime-mods, should be ok too ... not 100% but i suspect i will use values in range .. 1-100, 1-1000 or any other , so I can narrow it down to that range.

I dont want to , but If I have to ;(

... may be some sort of constraint satisfaction

---

my final goal is to generate sparse 1000 bit binary based the position of the small-reminder primes

```
 self.primes = np.array(nprimes(start=11,cnt=1000), dtype=DTYPE)
 np.random.shuffle(self.primes)
```

Looking for the decode() part !

Comment: Do the 980 other prime numbers give strictly greater reminders?

Comment: yeah they give greater reminders  ... unless 'strictly' has some other meaning

Comment: Not sure I understand what you are saying, but as I read this what you are asking is not possible.  For instance let $N$ satisfy $N\equiv 0 \pmod {p_i}$ for $i\in\{1,\cdots, 20\}$ and $N\equiv 1\pmod {p_i}$ if $i>20$.  Then let $M$ satisfy $M\equiv 0 \pmod {p_i}$ for $i\in\{1,\cdots, 20\}$ and $M\equiv 2\pmod {p_i}$ if $i>20$.  In each case you would just hand me the list $\{p_1, \cdots, p_{20}\}$, yes?  So how could I distinguish $N$ from $M$?

Comment: @lulu ... yeah that is ok...if I can find N,M,... because it is mod it is possible the solution/s is multiple numbers not just one .. which is also Ok, because I suspect there will be some connection between them ..

Comment: But there are many such, I just wrote down two.  Just knowing that $N\equiv 0 \pmod {p_i}$ for $i\in\{1,\cdots, 20\}$  tells us nothing other than that those primes divide $N$...and of course, you don't even know that since, as I understand it, all you have is the list $\{p_1, \cdots, p_{20}\}$.

Comment: To stress my point, consider a simpler case.  Say we just had two primes, $3,5$.  Then there are only $15$ cases to consider.  For each of $v\in \{3,4,6,7,8,9,12,13,14\}$ $3$ is the prime which gives the strictly  smaller residue so just knowing $\{3\}$ would not help you much at all in determining the value.

Comment: Is the integer $v$ known to be in some range? If so, how does that range compare with the $1000$ primes?

Comment: By the way, this has nothing whatsoever to do with [coding-theory](https://math.stackexchange.com/tags/coding-theory/info). Read thos tag wikis rather than adding tags at random.

Comment: But, I'm fairly sure there is an interesting question underlying all this if we limit $v$ to a range, and have the liberty to select those prime numbers smartly. It may be possible to get a high probability for that set of 20 primes to contain enough information to id that number. After all, there are $\binom{1000}{20}$ choices for the set of primes. That is a largish number, so there's a lot of information. I don't know how to use it, just there is a lot. Of course, if we don't restrict $v$ to some range, then there is no change.

Comment: I can do range .. I select sequential primes .. for the task at hand it may or may not work if primes are specially selected ... after selecting them i shuffle them to achieve random positions ... idxs-pos is what i'm looking for ergo..argsort()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By the Chinese Remainder theorem, you can retrieve your number modulo the product of the twenty primes. That might be enough for your number.

If not, you are stuck because you can hypothesize any combination of remainders with the other primes (that are larger than the twenty remainders) and retrieve *some* number.

Comment: looking .... but i don't have the reminders only the primes

Comment: @sten: then my intuition tells me that this is untractable, but I can't prove it.