# Solving system of modulo inequalities?

Tags: inequality, modular-arithmetic, systems-of-equations

I've already asked similar [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3739015/reversing-modulo-operation-system-of-equations), but back then I didn't know about modulo arithmetic.

I think I can ask it more clearly now.

Is this type of system of equations solvable? If yes, how?
$$
\begin{split}
    x \mod p_1 & < x \mod q_1\\
    x \mod p_1 & < x \mod q_2\\
    x \mod p_1 & < x \mod q_3\\
    \vdots & \\
    x \mod p_1 &< x \mod q_m\\
\\
    x \mod p_2 &< x \mod q_1\\
    x \mod p_2 &< x \mod q_2\\
    x \mod p_2 &< x \mod q_3\\
    \vdots &\\
    x \mod p_2 & < x \mod q_m\\
\\
    \vdots & \\
\\
    x \mod p_n &< x \mod q_1 \\
    x \mod p_n &< x \mod q_2 \\
    x \mod p_n &< x \mod q_3 \\
    \vdots &\\
    x \mod p_n &< x \mod q_m \\
\end{split}
$$
where $p$ and $q$ are all different prime numbers.

And if this system is solvable what is $x$?

You can also use the relation $\leq$ instead of $<$ in the inequalities above, if this simplifies the problem.

Comment: You are refering to the positive remainder operation as "$\mod {}$?

Comment: 3 mod 2 = 1,  i.e. 3 % 2 = 1

Answer (score 2):

As asked in [fleablood](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/280126/fleablood)'s question [comment](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3751639/solving-system-of-modulo-inequalities/3751649#comment7716152_3751639), it seems from the question context you're using $\bmod$ to refer to the non-negative remainder on division, e.g., $a = (b \bmod c)$ means $b = kc + a$, where $k$ is an integer, $c$ is positive integer and $0 \le a \lt c$. I'm going to assume this. Also, if so, then note there's no unique answer for $x$, although you can always do something like choose the smallest possible positive value as being the value you want..

To keep the discussion simpler, I'm also going to assume all $p_i$ and all $q_i$ are distinct. In that case, you can have

$$x \equiv y_1 \pmod{\prod_{i=1}^{n}p_i}, \; 0 \le y_1 \lt \min(p_1, p_2, \ldots, p_n, q_1 - 1, q_2 - 1, \ldots, q_m - 1) \tag{1}\label{eq1A}$$

$$x \equiv y_2 \pmod{\prod_{i=1}^{m}q_i}, \; y_1 \lt y_2 \lt \min(q_1, q_2, \ldots, q_m) \tag{2}\label{eq2A}$$

The first equation comes from that $x \equiv y_1 \pmod{\prod_{i=1}^{n}p_i}$ means $x \equiv y_1 \pmod{p_i}$ for all $i$, and similarly for the second equation. The limits on $y_1$ and $y_2$ ensure they will be equal to the remainder when divided by $p_i$ and $q_i$, respectively, and $y_1 \lt y_2$ to meet the question inequality conditions.

Note although \eqref{eq1A} and \eqref{eq2A} don't necessarily encompass all possible solutions, at least with these $2$ modular equations you have the [Chinese remainder theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chinese_remainder_theorem) guaranteeing a solution always exists.

An example which works in all cases is $y_1 = 0$ and $y_2 = 1$, i.e.,

$$x \equiv 0 \pmod{\prod_{i=1}^{n}p_i} \tag{3}$$

$$x \equiv 1 \pmod{\prod_{i=1}^{m}q_i} \tag{4}$$

Comment: how did you know y1=0, y2=1 ... does this follow because the divisors are different primes

Comment: @sten Since all primes are $\ge 2$, I knew that using $y_1 = 0$ and $y_2 = 1$ would always satisfy what I expressed in my ($1$) and ($2$) modulo equations, which would then also satisfy the requirements of your question.

Comment: thanks .. if u have time can u elaborate on how u came up with the two eqs.. i'm a programmer not a math guy, also new to CRT and %-arithmetic ;) and cant seem to figure why is it so..

Comment: because of the multiplications wouldnt the found X be too big ?

Comment: @sten I added some more details to the answer, which I hope helps you to understand. As for the multiplications causing "found X be too big", note this is not a problem since your question conditions only deal with the remainder when $x$ is divided by $p_i$ or $q_i$, not on its relative size. Thus, for example, you have $2 = (2 \bmod 5) = (98765432 \bmod 5)$. To have a value of $x$ which meets all of your conditions for any, including very large, values of $p_i$ and $q_i$, plus having $n$ and/or $m$ be quite large as well, will generally require $x$ to be very large.